# Image not loading from URL using Glide

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to load image into my ImageView but it is not working. I have tried nearly all suggested solutions on StackOverflow. This is my layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:contentScrim="@color/background"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/add_placemark"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="219dp"
                android:layout_height="89dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/addPlacemark_toolbar"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:translationZ="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addPlacemark_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:text='@={placemark.name,default="Add Placemark"}'
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/background"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addPlacemark_notes"
                    android:layout_width="225dp"
                    android:layout_height="37dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text='@={placemark.description,default="Add a new placemark by filling up details below"}'
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/background"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addPlacemark_title"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/addPlacemark_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarIconColor"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And this is the related code in my activity. The "Image loading" message is being logged but the image is not showing at all. The placeholder and error is not showing up as well

```
if (placemark.dp!=""){
  info("Image loading")
  GlideApp.with(this).placeholder(R.drawable.img_load)
      .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg").dontTransform().error(R.drawable.img_load)
      .into(dp)
}
```

Also, I have made sure Glide is integrated and initialized successfully into the project.

Comment: its a long shot, but did u provide Internet permission in your manifest file ?

Comment: Yes i did added the internet permission in my manifest

Comment: have you turned your internet on??

Comment: you call `load(...)` twice. It is intended? Otherwise try to remove the first `load(placemark.dp)`?

Comment: I accidentally added load() twice when testing. However removing it does not solve the issue. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @EdwardChew Did you try it without the `dontTransform()`? More on this [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transformations.html#automatic-transformations-for-imageviews)

Comment: @EdwardChew which version of glide do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android 4.0 or above and Glide dependency 4.12.0, I faced the same issue after some research I found that we should

1. Add .dontAnimate() before .into() 
   `Glide.with(this).load(url).dontAnimate().into(snapsImageView)`
2. Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest file inside application